# How can we define L-Infinity Norm for the multi-variable function?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

How can we define L-Infinity Norm for the multi-variable function?

For $$ \|f(t,x_1,\cdots,x_n)\|_\infty  = ?$$
where $f \in C^\infty ([0,\infty) \times \mathbb R^n) $.

Comment: Would you not define it basically the same way you define regular old $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ (the essential supremum)?

Comment: What happens if $f$ is not bounded?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the context. Sometimes you want $L^\infty_{x,t}$ which is the infimum of all numbers $M$ such that $|f(t,x)|\le M$ for a.e. $(x,t)$. In other situation you think of $t$ as evolving in time, and work with the norm $L^\infty_x$ obtained by fixing a value of $t$ and taking the infimum of all numbers $M$ such that $|f(t,x)|\le M$ for a.e. $x$.